# ZSH expansion for a timestamp?

Tags: zsh

My coworker has this nifty key combination he types in when `touch`ing a new file that expands out the current timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) to where the cursor is, so he can quickly create timestamped schema migration files, etc.

Alas, he's on vacation and I don't have access to his `.zshrc` file, and have been unsuccessful at finding out how to do this through Google. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function unix_ts { LBUFFER="${LBUFFER}$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')" }
zle -N unix_ts
bindkey "^t" unix_ts
```